# Keycloak Admin REST API: query more than 100 resource objects

Tags: rest, curl, keycloak

I have a client in Keycloak with more than 100 resources.
And I am trying to query the id of a resource with the Keycloak Admin REST API the following way:

```
RESOURCE_ID=$(curl -k -s -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" "$KEYCLOAK_URL/auth/admin/realms/$REALM/clients/$CLIENT_ID/authz/resource-server/resource" | jq -r '.[] | select(.name=="xy resource")._id')
```

Unfortunatelly "xy resource" is at the end of the alphabetically ordered list and the curl gives back only th first 100 resource objects.

Is there a way to query more than 100 records with the Keycloak Admin REST API or query directly the one with the given name?

I use Keycloak 12.0.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check REST API documentation, there are a lot of Query optional parameter 'max'

**Maximum results size (defaults to 100) integer(int32)**

https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/7.0/rest-api/

Comment: Great, it works: RESOURCE_ID=$(curl -k -s -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" "$KEYCLOAK_URL/auth/admin/realms/$REALM/clients/$CLIENT_ID/authz/resource-server/resource?max=500" | jq -r '.[] | select(.name=="xy resource")._id')

Comment: @DonatoSzilagyi I think if you do max=-1 it will get all and you don't need to specify the max

Comment: Thanks @dreamcrash, worked for me. 
In my case, just had to add to my Postman Collection the "max=-1" as a query param: https://{MY_KEYCLOACK_URL}/admin/realms/{MY_REALM}/users?max=-1
Thanks!!!

Comment: @hfunes.com you are welcome, I actually created an answer to increase visibility of my comment.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a client in Keycloak with more than 100 resources. And I am
> trying to query the id of a resource with the Keycloak Admin REST API

Go get more than 100 resources, you just need to set the max parameter to `-1` for example:

```
https://{KEYCLOACK_URL}/admin/realms/{MY_REALM}/users?max=-1
```